Why create a CGImage takes so much memory
I am now working on a photo app, but it has some memory overuse issues after I used the Instrument memory profiling tool.
I don't know if I got it right, but I found the cgimage takes more than 1 GB of memory for an image resolution around 1200*900?! Is there any way to prevent this?
The code relative to this image:
var image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(buffer)!)
let cgImage = context.createCGImage(image, from: image.extent)

Here is the screenshot of the profiler.

To further test it, I load an 8000*6000 image from disk into a CIImage, then create a CVPixelBuffer, and use the buffer to create a new CIIamge finally render it into CGImage
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "IMG_4071", withExtension: "HEIC")
let ciimage = CIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: url!))!
print(ciimage.extent)//(0.0, 0.0, 6048.0, 8064.0)
let context = CIContext()
var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer?
let attrs = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue] as CFDictionary
let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(ciimage.extent.width), Int(ciimage.extent.height), kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, attrs, &pixelBuffer)
        context.render(ciimage, to: pixelBuffer!)
let newCiimage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)
        
let cgimage = context.createCGImage(newCiimage, from: newCiimage.extent)
        cgimageArray.append(cgimage!)


This time it only takes 100M memory. Is it because the first cvbuffer comes from the camera buffer data which is bigger? Or do the numbers in the profiling have some other meaning?

What iszoom(to:)? What is cropFactor? Does it perhaps return something much larger than 1200*900? Back of the envelope, it looks like you've possibly accidentally scaled your image by ~250x. (maybe it's 255 or 256, a nice power of 2 that you've applied by accident?)

@RobNapier I print out the extent of the image after zoom, the size is normal.

The numbers are total allocations sampled for that block of code. If it is called many times, it is the sum of all of those times that it was sampled, not per-call. But also, extent is in working space coordinates, not pixels. It matters what zoom is doing. I would try getting rid of it and seeing if it changes things. Make the code you want to check exactly close as possible to the code you believe is corret. Get rid of all other pieces.
